# Lost menu bar on all programs

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, menu-bar

All of my programs have either lost the menu bar or it shows up in my panel(as in VLC).

Is there some global setting causing that?

[image]

Comment: Do you remember if you did something that might have caused this?

Comment: You have some plugin enabled. Mate features a "Unity" mode that creates a global menu. You will need to cleanup your settings a bit.

Comment: @vanadium I need some more details. What do you mean by "clean up your settings."?

Comment: Not using Mate, so cannot give you details. But the possibility to have a global menu in Mate is there.